# Can you can define 'page_objects_path' directory which will read from all sub-folders without specifying them explicitly?

Tags: node.js, automation, cucumber, nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

The project that I am currently working on, uses Selenium WebDriver Nightwatch and Cucumber.

The issue is that project's folder structure has changed and now **'page_objects_path'** in **'nightwatch.conf.js'** file looks something like this:

```
'page_objects_path':
    [
        "./componentTests/page-objects",
        "./componentTests/page-objects/xxxxxx",
        "./componentTests/page-objects/xxxxx xxxx",
        "./endToEndTests/page-objects",
        "./endToEndTests/page-objects/xxxx",
        "./endToEndTests/page-objects/xxxxxxx",
        "./endToEndTests/page-objects/xxxx xxxxx",
        "./endToEndTests/page-objects/xxxxxx"
        "./endToEndTests/page-objects/xxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
```

Is there any way, where Nightwatch can read all sub-folders from /page-objects/ directory without being explicitly specified in the array as separate paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

```
'page_objects_path':
    [
        "./componentTests/page-objects",
        "./endToEndTests/page-objects",
    ],
```

should be enough.
The `page` class should have sub-classes called by the sub-folders of your structure. 
E.g. the method `getTheCoolElement()` from "./endToEndTests/page-objects/mainPage/SubPage.js" should be called like: `browser.page.mainPage.SubPage().getTheCoolElement()`

See working example in owncloud phoenix project, that has a hierarchy of page objects: https://github.com/owncloud/phoenix/tree/master/tests/acceptance/pageObjects

alternatively you could just create that array programmatically using JS. e.g.

```
const fs = require('fs')
// const path = require('path')

const getAllFolders = function (dirPath, arrayOfFiles) {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath)

  arrayOfFiles = arrayOfFiles || []

  files.forEach(function (file) {
    if (fs.statSync(dirPath + '/' + file).isDirectory()) {
      arrayOfFiles = getAllFolders(dirPath + '/' + file, arrayOfFiles)
      arrayOfFiles.push(path.join(dirPath, '/', file))
    }
  })

  return arrayOfFiles
}

let allPageObjectPath = getAllFolders(
  path.join(__dirname, '/componentTests/page-objects')
)
allPageObjectPath = allPageObjectPath.concat(
  getAllFolders(path.join(__dirname, '/endToEndTests/page-objects'))
)

module.exports = {
  page_objects_path: allPageObjectPath,
....
}
```

Comment: The first suggestion is not the best option, because if you rename one of the files, then you should replace on all places. 
Can you please add more details about the second option?
"alternatively you could just create that array programmatically using JS"

Comment: I've edited my answer, please have a look it that helps you